# `pstricks` package preventing compilation

Tags: miktex, pstricks, debugging

Today I updated to the latest version of MiKTeX (2.9.6703, I was previously using an older version of MiKTeX 2.9) and now the `pstricks` package entirely prevents me from compiling a document when loaded using `\usepackage{pstricks}`. Thus, the code below produces fatal error messages, but commenting out `\usepackage{pstricks}` means the document compiles just fine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

I get 100 identical error messages saying:

> ! Text line contains an invalid character.
>   l.1 ...@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@
>                                                     ^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^...

I get the same errors whether I use XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX of pdfLaTeX.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

(Edit: This question was originally about `pst-asr` but it seems the problem is actually with `pstricks`, on which `pst-asr` is dependent.)

Comment: This document compiles fine with XeLaTeX or `latex + dvips`. It won't compile properly with pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX although it shouldn't produce the error you show. I'm using TL2018.  Try deleting the `.aux` files and recompiling with XeLaTeX.

Comment: they are byte 0, ascii NULL so you have a corrupted file but it is impossible to say from the small fragment of log shown which file is bad

Comment: Thanks! It looks like my installation of `iftex` was corrupted; un- and reinstalling has got rid of the error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.